# Fitgrid - Adding a border to the edge of a column

Tags: html, css, border

Please forgive my ignorance as I am new to this forum as well as webdesign. I am using fitgrid to build a website and I would like to add borders to a footer that I have made but I cannot work out how to do it. Can anyone help. Here is my code:

```
<!--Footer--> 
<div class="row"> 
    <footer>
        <div class="fg3">
            <img src="images/rics-logo-white-small.png" alt="RICS Logo" class="footerlogo1">
            <img src="images/APSLogo-small.png" alt="APS Logo" class="footerlogo2">
        </div>
        <div class="fg2">
            <h3 class="h3-footer">Address...</h3>
                    <p class="footer-text">Basin Road<br>Newhaven<br>East Sussex<br>BN22 1NP</p>
        </div>
        <div class="fg5">
            <h3 class="h3-footer">Navigate Our Site...</h3>
                    <p class="footer-text">HOME<br>ABOUT US<br>CASE STUDIES<br>SERVICES<br>CLIENTS<br>ECO<br>CONTACT US<br>BUILDING SURVEYING<br>PROJECT MANAGEMENT<br>PROFESSIONAL SERVICES<br>INSURANCE WORKS<br>ENERGY CONSERVATION<br>EXPERT ADVICE</p>
        </div>
        <div class="fg2">
            <h3 class="h3-footer">Like Us...</h3>
                    <p class="footer-text">Linkedin Logo and Twitter logo to go in this little section here.....</p>
        </div>
    </footer>
</div>
<!--Footer END-->
```

I would like it to look like this image..... [imgur.com/kG0c5oB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1MBX.jpg)

Thanks

Dave

Comment: Could you include your CSS?

Comment: the css to add a border to the footer is: footer{ border: size type color; } 
so u can say footer{ border: 2px solid #000;}

Comment: This is my CSS for the h3 div:.h3-footer {
  margin-bottom: 0.3em;
  font-size: 1.8em;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: left; 
}   does that help @Jaxon

Comment: Put the image in imgur.com and put a link to it here.

Comment: Thanks @Jaxon - here is the link: http://imgur.com/kG0c5oB

Comment: So does my answer work for you?

Comment: Sorry @Jaxon it didn't work. See the comment on your below answer

Comment: If my answer works for you, I would appreciate you accepting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the look of the image, I would recommend this code:

```
footer .fg3{
   border-right: 1px white solid;
}

footer .fg5{
       border-right: 1px white solid;
       border-left: 1px white solid;
}
```

Then you can change any of the styles that may be a little off.
Hope it works!

Comment: Sorry @Jaxon, that's not what I meant. I am looking to achieve the borders on the right of each of the footer information sections, you can just see it on the mockup i think.

Comment: Edited answer for you.